# Use the first Row like Column Name. Data Frame of factors

Tags: r, xlsx

I'm using a dataframe of factors and I need to use the first row of the DF as column names. My problem is the next when I make

```
>DF[1,]
 DF[1,]
 TradeStation.Trade.List  NA.     NA..1  NA..2 NA..3          NA..4
1                       # Type Date/Time Signal Price Roll Over Pips
                         NA..5                       NA..6    NA..7
1 Shares/Ctrts/Units - Profit/Loss Net Profit - Cum Net Profit % Profit
        NA..8      NA..9     NA..10 NA..11   NA..12
1 Run-up/Drawdown Efficiency Total Eff.  Comm. Slippage
```

If I make names(DF) <- DF[1,] I receive the number of different factors as name, not the first row.

How can I do that??

Thank you very much

PD: I have gotten the dataframe from read.xlx() from the xlsx library

Comment: as @RHertel pointed out, you probably just want `header=TRUE` or `colNames=TRUE` in your read function

Comment: I just read an Excel sheet with `read.xlsx` and the column names were identified automatically, even without using the option `header=T`. What is your output of `colnames(DF)`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to coerce the factors to be characters instead of their integer representations

```
dat <- data.frame(a=factor(letters[1:10]),
                  b=factor(letters[11:20]))

out <- setNames(dat[-1,], sapply(dat[1,], as.character))

#    a k
# 2  b l
# 3  c m
# 4  d n
# 5  e o
# 6  f p
# 7  g q
# 8  h r
# 9  i s
# 10 j t
```

Comment: I have another solution. My problem with the headers start because the headers are not at the first line, so I only have to start from another line. The final code is this:

    ops <- read.xlsx("output.xlsx", sheetIndex = 1,startRow = 3)